Generating custom report using Esri web applications
I've built an ArcGIS dashboard that shows environmental data for > 100 countries, which can be filtered by country. In the data table, the first field contains countries and the rows contain corresponding information for each country. I want to include a function that would enable users to extract and download data for a given country in a report (ideally a pdf), but have not yet been able to find a way to do this in AGOL. I've accomplished this using an R Shiny app, but would like to eliminate reliance on non-Esri technology if possible.
Is there a pathway within any of ESRI's web app solutions to enable users to select a country from a list and download a formatted report detailing all corresponding data for that country?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site, where the most frequent comments are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" Broad discussion-oriented Questions are likely to be closed. Boolean questions, such as "Is it possible?"  and "Has anyone done this?" are only likely to result in a "Yes" answer (which is not likely to be helpful). Please make sure you ask the question you want answered, and that the Question specifies what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Check out the following article - https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/print-from-layout-items/. I've seen some conflicting information with regards to what license level is required, but in theory a report style layout with dynamic fields would enable this. Haven't personally attempted this yet though.

@AustinAverill This is great, will have a look - thanks!
